# Pandas dataframe indexing with negative index

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with syntax:

```
df[df.index[-1]+1]=['James','1' ,'Active']
```

What does the -1 +1 syntax do?

Comment: It creates a new column with a label `last_index + 1` and sets its values equal to that list

Comment: this is a short but a bit difficult to read way of inserting a column and is equivalent to `df.insert(len(df.columns), df.index[-1]+1, ['James','1' ,'Active'])` which makes it much clearer in my opinion